# In the Python for loop, I can't get the expected counter value

Tags: python, speech-recognition

A speaker recognition project using the assemblyzer module. The folder structure is as follows: there is a directory `speakers`, which contains folders `spk1`, `spk2`, etc. Each folder contains several recordings of individual speakers (one folder - one speaker). During processing, I made a dictionary in which the keys are the same directories `spk1`, `spk2`, etc., and their values are embedding (representations) of speaker recordings.

Next, I want to compare the recordings of each speaker in pairs to calculate the accuracy metric (how often the system makes mistakes). At this **first stage** of the script below, I do the following: I create pairwise combinations in order to sort through all possible combinations of records of any speaker inside "his" folder.

**The second stage** is to write the embeds of records into similarity matrices and compare them by means of cosine similarity.

In the final (**third stage**) we consider accuracy. We see: we went through 46 combinations, but for some reason we got 0 matches. Although if you print out the similarity matrices, it is obvious that there are coincidences. What's wrong with the for loop?

Previously, a similar problem occurred when I solved the same problem using the speechbrain library. Then the counting error was associated with a tensor data type that generates logical responses `True` or `False`. Here, as it seems to me, is a different case.

Code:

```
!pip install resemblyzer
! pip install umap
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations

num_true=0
num_total=0

# Stage 1 - for the sake of comparison, we sort through the dictionary values (i.e. embeddings of speakers' records) and create a list of all possible combinations:
# (speaker 1 record 1 - speaker 1 record 2), (speaker 1 record 1 - speaker 1 record 3), etc.
for elems in speaker_wavs.values():   
  # print(elems[0])
  tuples = list(combinations(elems, 2)) # we get a search of all combinations
 
  # Stage 2 - create embeddings of records
  for single in tuples:         # we go through each combination in the list
      # the .embed_utterance() function creates voice embeddings
      embeds = (np.array( [encoder.embed_utterance(single[0]) ] ), np.array([encoder.embed_utterance(single[1]) ] ) )
      num_total+=1

      # Let's calculate the similarity matrix. The similarity of two embeddings is simply their dot product, 
      # because the similarity metric is cosine similarity, and embeddings are already normalized by L2.

      # Short version:
      utt_sim_matrix = np.inner(embeds[0], embeds[1])    # The inner product of two arrays 
      # print('Matrix_1', utt_sim_matrix) # print it out if you need to visually compare embeddings
    
      # Long, detailed version:
      utt_sim_matrix2 = np.zeros( (len(embeds[0]), len(embeds[1]) ) )
      for i in range(len(embeds[0])):
        for j in range(len(embeds[1])):
        # The @ notation is equivalent to np.dot(embedds_a[i], embedds_b[i])
          utt_sim_matrix2[i, j] = embeds[0][i] @ embeds[1][j]
          # print('Matrix_2', utt_sim_matrix2)  # print it out if you need to visually compare embeddings

          # Returns True if two arrays are equal in elements within the tolerance       
          if np.allclose(utt_sim_matrix, utt_sim_matrix2) == 'True':
            num_true+=1

# print(num_true)   # now we get 0
# print(num_total)  # now we get 46

# Stage 3 - counting the accuracy metric:
if num_total !=0:
  accuracy = num_true/num_total
  print(accuracy)
else:
  print('You can't divide by zero')
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem like this:

```
if str(np.allclose(utt_sim_matrix, utt_sim_matrix2)) == 'True':
            num_true+=1
```

Thus, I explicitly converted the response to a string type